# Notepad++ shortcuts not getting copied to the second computer where I want to replicate my settings

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

In Notepad++, there's a way to assign your custom shortcuts by going to
Run -> Modify Shortcut/Delete Command...

This brings up the Shortcut Mapper

I set up my custom shortcuts on 
Computer 1
I then installed Notepad++ with the same install settings and plugins on
Computer 2

I then created a zip archive of my Notepad++ folder in Program Files on Computer 1
I overwrote the Notepad++ folder in Program Files on Computer 2 with this archive

My custom shortcuts did not come across.
I thought that the shortcuts were saved in
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml

I compared
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml
from Computer 1 with the same file on Computer 2 and the
two files are identical.

Why then are the shortcuts not coming across to Computer 2?

Computer 1 is Windows XP
Computer 2 is Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that it stores those shortcut maps in `shortcuts.xml`, but it's not saved to the one in the Notepad++ folder (at least not by default on Windows).

It's instead saved to your user's AppData folder:

- On Windows Vista+ check `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++`
- On Windows XP check `C:\Documents and Settings\<your user name>\Application Data\Notepad++`

Also, it appears that changes are not saved to that file until you close Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks, I need to build a script to put everything in the right place.  Funny thing is when I installed Notepad++ on Windows Server 2008 R2 I checked the "Do not use %APPDATA%" option. I guess this option is useless on later Win versions.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Computer 2 (Windows Server 2008 R2) has a path

```
C:\Users\<user.domain>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
```

where it gets all the settings that Computer 1 (Windows XP) was getting from

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++
```

Turns out I needed to copy and replace the following files from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
```

to

```
C:\Users\<user.domain>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++>tree /F /A 
|   config.xml
|   contextMenu.xml
|   langs.xml
|   session.xml
|   shortcuts.xml
|   stylers.xml
|
\---plugins
    \---Config
        |   Compare.ini
        |   converter.ini
        |   Fileswitcher.ini
        |   npes_saved.txt
        |   NppExec.ini
        |   NppExternalLexers.xml
        |   NppExternalLexers.xml.backup
        |   NppExternalLexers.xml.backup2
        |   NppExtLexer_PluginHelp.txt
        |   NppPlugin_ChangeMarker.xml
        |   NppPlugin_PluginMargin.xml
        |   NppPlugin_SciMarkerSymbol.xml
        |   NppTextFX.ini
        |   PluginManager.ini
        |   PluginManagerPlugins.xml
        |   PythonScriptStartup.cnf
        |   RegRexPlace.ini
        |   SpellChecker.ini
        |   WndMgr.ini
        |
        +---NppFTP
        |       Certificates.xml
        |       NppFTP.xml
        |
        \---PythonScript
            \---scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **CLOSE** all working notepad++ windows.
2. There are two shortcuts.xml files. Synchronize at these locations:

   - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
     (or C:\Documents and Settings\SoftVnn Member\Application Data\Notepad++)
   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
     (or C:\Program Files\Notepad++)

Then you've successful migrated the shorcut keys.